# Why Expect: 100 Continue header splitting response in 2

Tags: javascript, http, browser, cors, csrf

I am a security researcher while researching on a project I found that when I insert Expect: 100-continue header in request response comes like this :

```
 HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\cr\lf
    \cr\lf

    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Server: CloudFront
    Date: Tue, 07 Nov 2023 08:06:33 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 167
    Connection: close
    Location: https://redacted.com/test.js
    X-Cache: Redirect from cloudfront
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Vary: Origin

    <html>
    <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
    <body>
    <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
    <hr><center>CloudFront</center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Like sending 2 responses in one request 100 continue with 301 redirect with two \cr\lf in it.

I want to know if it is that then other 301 redirect response should act like HTTP payload and any script in it should be rendered in browser because anything that comes after two \cr\lf means headers are ended and now payload is started.

As I mention I am a security researcher then how can I make a Proof of Concept triggering an XSS.

Main point to be noted:

This is a simple HTTP to HTTPS upgrading request most website handle this by redirecting HTTP to HTTPS.

```
Expect : 100 continue header is the exploit in the request.
```

I tried many ways but browser is not rendering XSS simply redirecting the request to Location: header.

Location header is vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: "*I want to know if it is that then other 301 redirect response should act like HTTP payload*" - no. The 301 response is **not** the payload of the 100 response, it is indeed a separate, second response to the request. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-informational-1xx

Comment: I think you got it wrong. Do you know about \cr\lf injection in bug bounty, if no then it means that if you anyhow inject \cr\lf in responce and response got splitted in two responsec making another half responce as HTTP payload because anything comes after two \cr\lf it should be prompt as HTTP payload. Most of time hunter injects \cr\lf through links or open redirection. Like:

Comment: But in my case 100 continue header injects \cr\lf itself and location header is vulnerbale to XSS thats why I m asking why browsers are not rendering XSS

Comment: In normal scenario till date I dont find Two HTTP status in single response.

Comment: It is not a single response. It's two responses, admittedly on the same connection.

Comment: Bro for easy demonstration see that : - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN8WF1q04no&t=576s     . In this video you can easily understand what I am try to say

Comment: So what? No, a 100 response cannot be used for desync attacks.

Answer (score 0):

No, the 301 response does not act as payload of the 100 response. It's two separate responses (on the same connection). See the [HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-informational-1xx):

> A 1xx response is terminated by the end of the header section; it cannot contain content or trailers.
>
> A client **MUST** be able to parse one or more 1xx responses received prior to a final response, even if the client does not expect one.

Of course, you may find buggy HTTP clients, but it's unlikely you will be able to run an injection attack on a browser.